# How we can access to this of controller nestjs

Tags: nestjs

I have property which is configService and I want to access to this property inside an object. How can I do that?

This is the property in the constructor:

```
@Controller('user')
export class UserController {
  
    constructor(
  private  userService:UserService,
  private  configService:ConfigService

    ){
      
    }

    
    
    @UseGuards(JwtAuthGuard)
    @Get()
    say(@CurrentUser() user){
      return 'hello user you are '+user.profil+' and your id info is '+user.userProfil.id +' '+this.configService.get('DEST_FORMATIONS')
    }
```

here it works and it print the variable DEST_FORMATIONS of file .env

but here it doesn't work

```
@UseInterceptors(FileInterceptor('file', {
 
  storage:diskStorage({destination:  this.configService.get('DEST_FORMATIONS'), ...
```

How can I do it?

Comment: why not configuring this destination as default option? https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/file-upload#async-configuration

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use configuration outside Nest's IoC container, you can try [nest-typed-config](https://github.com/Nikaple/nest-typed-config#using-config-outside-nests-ioc-container-usage-in-decorators):

```js
import { selectConfig } from 'nest-typed-config';
import { ConfigModule, FileConfig } from '@/module/config';

const fileConfig = selectConfig(ConfigModule, FileConfig);

@UseInterceptors(FileInterceptor('file', {
  storage: diskStorage({
    destination: fileConfig.destination
  })
}))
```